# RWD theme - mobile view - IE browser

Tags: magento-1.9, css, rwd-theme

The Magento stock RWD theme does not respond well in a IE 11 browser. Account is on top of the logo. Minicart.phtml does not appear in IE. How can we find a resolution to this issue?

Screenshot below of IE and Chrome browsers. 
[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems some RWD styles are not integrated or imported correctly and check with media screen css too. As dhiewo said the meta tag may be a problem for IE use the meta  tag in **app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

If still issue exists check your css path and folder.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [bootsrap issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11284) , add this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

i think it would be fine with that meta.

Comment: Thank you @dhiewo This theme is not based on Bootstrap its rwd. Where should I place the meta tag in Magento?